# How to change GoogleMaps physical relief with maps API on Flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex, google-maps, maps

Well, I have an app in Flex using Google Maps API (with Map3D) and I receive GPS data that basically is Latitude,Longitude and Altitude.
well... I want to show the marker in my app also changing the altitude of the location I received the data.
Is there anyway of doing that? How?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Do you want to visually show the 'altitude' changing on the marker somehow, or do you just want the marker to show that data?

Comment: I guess I wasn't very clear. I want do visually show the altitude changing the marker or even the map, I know I can overlay with Papervision3D, but I don't know how to change the relief
(here an example of PaperVision 3d http://shiba.iis.u-tokyo.ac.jp/member/ueyama/gmap-pv-demo/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are talking about as well.

Have a look at the [marker options](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/flash/reference.html#MarkerOptions) in the API reference.

Here's [how to implement custom markers](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/flash/overlays.html#Markers)